# Hover over a point of an image and text appears on the side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image and on the image is a timeline with 4 numbers. I want text to appear next to the image when I hover over one of the numbers. How do I do this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: It's javascript and not java so you will need to change the tag.

Comment: You need to use map and area. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Answer (score 0):

there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/zcps7xef/

html

```
<div id="contain">
<a>text</a>
    <div class="text">other text</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#contain{
    clear: both;
}

a{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14px;
}

#contain:hover div.text{
    display: block;
}

.text{
    float: left; 
    display: none;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! but to text. How do I do the same effect when I hover over different positions on my image?

Comment: i imagine that you could change .text to img, change div.text to div.img and just use the img tag on html, you can also put your code on jsfiddle or copepen so that i could see a better example and from there i will be able to understand better what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: How can i send you a screenshot so you can see it ?

Comment: follow this link:https://imgur.com/upload and paste the url here once it is done so i can see it

Comment: ok... i understand now, but i also need a screenshot of your code to analyze it better because at the moment i am just assuming what it has behind